# "Только победа!" Тип предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Только победа!

Какой это тип предложения? Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 1):

Номинативная конструкция, которая может иметь **разную функцию** в зависимости от ситуации.

1) **Изолированный постпозитивный номинатив:** Все люди на стадионе были единой массой, были связаны одним порывом и чувствовали одинаково. Только победа!

2) **Изолированный номинатив в препозиции**: Только победа! Как часто в истории человечества и в жизни отдельных людей звучали эти слова.

3) **Неполное двусоставное предложение (лозунг)**: Только победа (нам нужна)! Сказуемое определяется по ситуации.

4) **Номинативное предложение**: Стадион опустел. Разочарованные, люди постепенно расходятся, а под ногами валяется уже никому ненужный плакат. Я переворачиваю его. Только победа! Напоминание о несостоявшемся празднике.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В чем отличия 1 и 4 случая? Не является ли 4 случай тоже постпозитивным номинативом?

Comment: И скандирование на стадионе "Только победа!" не является ли номинативным предложением?

Comment: Пункт 4 - это надпись, которую видит наблюдатель на брошенном плакате.  Скандирование - это пожелание победы.

Comment: Почему скандирование на стадионе - это неполное предложение, а надпись на плакате, которая тоже пожелание - номинативное предложение?

Comment: Люди скандируют лозунг во время игры, выражая своё желание, требуя победы. А после матча наблюдатель проходит вдоль рядов и видит надпись на брошенном плакате. Впрочем, это всего лишь моё мнение, ориентированное на определения номинативных конструкций различного вида.